# Next highly composite number?

Tags: fourier-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

R language has this function 'nextn' ([link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nextn.html)) which computes the next highly composite number greater than a given one, which is used to find the  optimal padding size for the subsequent FFT operation.

So I am looking for similar *Mathematica* function

```
NextHighlyCompositeNumber[ n_Integer?Positive, primes:{__Integer?PrimeQ} ]
```

which will output the smallest number $m \geqslant n$ such that $m = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ for some non-negative exponents $e_k$.

This seems to be a combinatorial search kind of problem, which could be solved using integer linear programming (if available).

Comment: So, using `RLink` is not an option, I guess?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin A solution in _Mathematica_ proper would be preferable.

Answer (score 9):

Minimization can be expressed with plain `NMinimize` in a bit awkward manner:

```
NextHighlyCompositeNumber[n_Integer?Positive, primes:{__Integer?PrimeQ}] :=
  With[{parms = Unique[] & /@ primes}, 
    With[{eqn = Inner[Power, primes, parms, Times]}, 
      Floor@First@NMinimize[{eqn, eqn >= n &&
        parms \[Element] Integers && And @@ (# >= 0 & /@ parms)}, parms]]]

AbsoluteTiming@Table[NextHighlyCompositeNumber[n, {2, 3, 5}], {n, 1, 10}]

(* {3.063287, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

Alternatively, a shorter but more explicit exposition is possible using `LinearProgramming`:

```
NextHighlyCompositeNumber[n_Integer?Positive, primes:{__Integer?PrimeQ}] := 
  Quiet@Inner[Power, primes, 
    LinearProgramming[Log[primes], {Log[primes]}, {Log[n]}, Automatic, Integers],
    Times]

AbsoluteTiming@Table[NextHighlyCompositeNumber[n, {2, 3, 5}], {n, 1, 50}]

(* {0.140417, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 16, 18,
    18, 20, 20, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 27, 27, 30, 30, 30, 32, 32, 36, 36,
    36, 36, 40, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 48, 48, 48, 50, 50}} *)
```

Idea in the latter case is to turn product-of-powers representing all possible values representable by these primes into sum-of-products by applying logarithm on all constraints. This makes the problem a dot product which is, naturally, amenable to linear programming.

Explicit `LinearProgramming` implementation (or variant of `NMinimize` that would have been written to the same form) is dramatically faster and numerically easier to evaluate.

**EDIT:**

Not so surprisingly, generating consecutive highly composite numbers is much faster than integer linear programming approach. This tail-recursive code achieves it (sorry, it's bit of a mess, nowhere near elegant):

```
HighlyCompositesTo[n_Integer?Positive, primes:{__Integer?PrimeQ}] :=
  HighlyCompositesTo[n, primes, {1}, 1 & /@ primes, primes, Min[primes]]

HighlyCompositesTo[n_, primes_, list_, pos_, next_, min_] := list /; Last[list] >= n

HighlyCompositesTo[n_, primes_, list_, pos_, next_, min_] := 
  With[{nlist = Append[list, min],
    npos = MapThread[If[#1 == min, #2 + 1, #2] &, {next, pos}]}, 
    With[{nnext = MapThread[If[#1 == min, #3 nlist[[#2]], #1] &, {next, npos, primes}]},
      HighlyCompositesTo[n, primes, nlist, npos, nnext, Min[nnext]]]]
```

This performs much better than `NextHighlyCompositeNumber` in extracting values up to 10000:

```
HighlyCompositesTo[10000, {2, 3, 5, 7}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.007496, Null} *)

NestWhileList[NextHighlyCompositeNumber[# + 1, {2, 3, 5, 7}] &,
  1, # < 10000 &]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {5.247371, Null} *)
```

Both produce the same result:

```
NestWhileList[NextHighlyCompositeNumber[# + 1, {2, 3, 5, 7}] &, 1, # < 10000 &] ==
  HighlyCompositesTo[10000, {2, 3, 5, 7}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Yes, this is using ILP.

Comment: @BrettChampion Yes, my first attempt was already ILP. In case someone wonders how your comment relates to my answer, the answer was extensively edited...

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this problem is to make a list and then just choose from the list. The first 1200 highly composite numbers are given [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.txt). The largest one is order 10^87 so it is unlikely that you would need to go higher than this when doing a FFT. Here is a stripped down version:

```
highlyComposite[n_] := Module[{comps = {2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 120, 128, 180, 240, 
  256, 360, 512, 720, 840, 1024, 1260, 1680, 2048, 2520, 4096, 5040, 7560, 
  8192, 10080, 15120, 16384, 20160, 25200, 27720, 32768, 45360, 
  50400, 55440, 65536, 83160, 110880, 131072, 166320, 221760, 
  262144, 277200, 332640, 498960, 524288, 554400, 665280, 720720, 
  1048576, 1081080, 1441440, 2097152, 2162160, 2882880, 3603600, 
  4194304, 4324320, 6486480, 7207200, 8388608, 8648640, 10810800, 
  14414400, 16777216, 17297280, 21621600, 32432400, 33554432, 
  36756720, 43243200, 61261200, 67108864, 73513440, 110270160, 
  122522400}}, 
  First[Select[comps, # > n &]]]
```

You can use this to find the next larger (highly composite number) than `n`. For instance, `highlyComposite[121]` returns 128 and `highlyComposite[10000]` gives 10080.

Comment: For all the practical applications this is probably the way to go, but it does not take the second argument into account.

Comment: If you are using it for FFT length, why does it matter how the current number factors? It would appear that the only thing of importance is to get a highly composite number for the FFT calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers you seek are a generalized form of [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), composed of an arbitrary list of primes rather than simply a list of the first few primes. Dijkstra's algorithm, given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505894/tricky-google-interview-question/5506635#5506635), generates numbers, in increasing order up from 1, which contain only non-negative powers of primes less than a maximum. Translated and tweeked for your problem, the code becomes the following.

```
NextHighlyComposite[n_Integer, p_List] :=
   Block[{i = Length[p], r, c, v, s, m = {1}},
         r = Range[i];
         c = ConstantArray[1, i];
         v = c;
         While[
               (s = Min[v = p*m[[c]]]) < n,
               c[[Pick[r, v, s]]] += 1;
               m = Flatten[{m, s}]];
         s = Min[v = p*m[[c]]];
         c[[Pick[r, v, s]]] += 1;
         s]
```

This code is very fast, not slowed by `FactorInteger` or `NMinimize`, and generalizes the approach by @bills to include an arbitrary list of primes.

```
Map[NextHighlyComposite[#, {2, 3, 5}] &, {47, 100, 101, 1001, 10001}]
(* {48,100,108,1024,10125} *)

NextHighlyComposite[1017, {7, 11, 13}]
(* 1183 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the definition in R and testing:

```
fac[n_, p_] := 
 Or @@ (FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]] == # & /@ (Rest@Subsets[p]))
nc[n_, p_] := NestWhile[# + 1 &, n, ! fac[#, p] &]
```

Some R examples:

[image]

and

```
nc[#, {2, 3, 5}] & /@ {47, 100, 101, 1001, 10001}
```

yields:

```
{48, 100, 108, 1024, 10125}
```

Similarly,

[image]

```
nc[103, {3, 5, 7}]
nc[1017, {7, 11, 13}]
```

yield 105 and 1183 respectively.

**UPDATE**

See comments. **Sasha** has instructively pointed out code inefficiency. Sasha's code follows:

```
fac2[n_, p_List] := With[{pr = FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]}, Intersection[pr, p] =!= pr]; 
nc2[n_, p_] := NestWhile[# + 1 &, n, fac2[#, p] &].
```

Comment: Thank you. I should point few inefficiencies in your code. Note that `FactorInteger[n]` is called within the body of the pure function, i.e. your code factors `n` for `2^Length[p]-1` times. This can be inefficient. Perhaps more efficient would be `fac2[n_, p_List] := With[{pr = FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]}, Intersection[pr, p] =!= pr];
nc2[n_, p_] := NestWhile[# + 1 &, n, fac2[#, p] &]`. Then your version `nc[1230233, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}]` takes 0.4 seconds, while `nc2[1230233, {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}]` takes only 0.03, while giving the same answer of `1232000`.

Comment: @Sasha thank you for the instructive advice...my time limited aim was to reproduce the `R` implementation and agree entirely `subset` for large list of primes would be unwieldy but for specified purpose, most of time 3 primes, not too expensive...but accept entirely your more efficient code.

Comment: @Sasha I will add as update with attribution to you

Comment: @Sasha FYI `nextn(1230233,factors=c(2,3,5,7,11))` in R also yields...`1232000` but I assume you already know that